# next auth not passing all user info to the client

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to have a role for the user in the session

This is what I get from `session.user` on the client :

```js
{ "email": "test value" }
```

what I want to get :

```js
{ 
  "email": "test value",
  "role": "user"
}
```

For some reason I can access the role on the server side but not on the client

[...nextauth].ts :

```js
//..
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials as {
          email: string;
          password: string;
        };
        const saltRounds = 10;

        const db = path.join(process.cwd(), "db");

        const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(db + "/users.json", "utf-8"));

        type User = {
          id: string;
          email: string;
          name: string;
          role: "user" | "admin";
          password: string;
        };

        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          const e = users[i] as User;

          const emailMatch = e.email === email;

          if (emailMatch) {
            const passwordMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(password, e.password);

            if (passwordMatch) {
              console.log("user loggedin", e);

              return {
                id: e.id,
                email: e.email,
                name: e.name,
                role: e.role,
              };
            }
          }
        }

        throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt(params) {
      if (params.user?.role) {
        params.token.role = params.user.role;
      }
      console.log("jwt", params);
      return params.token;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

I have tried searching for how to do it and I dont see what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not setting the `session` you have to use the session callback to update the `session` from the returned `token`:

```js
async jwt(params) {
  if (params.user?.role) {
    params.token.role = params.user.role;
  }
  if (params.user?.email) {
    params.token.email = params.user.email;
  }
  return params.token;
},
async session({ session, token }) {
  session.role = token.role;
  session.email = token.email;
  return session;
},
```

> For some reason I can access the role on the server side but not on the client

that's the role from the `token` because you have added the property `role` to it now you have to add properties to your `session`